# Struct alignment suggestions?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, struct

I am sending data over a network. To send that data over a network I am packing it into a byte array.

Right now the data type consist of a byte and 3 floats making it 13 bytes total. To read this I need to know the size of the structure. Using Marshal's sizeOf does not return the "correct" size of my serialized byte array.

Now I know what is happening. Marshal is returning me the managed aligned size of my struct. I also know if I flag it

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,
Pack = 1)]
```

then it will return the "correct" size. My question is what is the best approach? I know the reason it adds in the padding bits is because the processor likes everything to be aligned (if I'm not mistaken, feel free to correct me!)

Is the performance penalty worth doing this so I can use sizeof to deserialize the array, or would it be better to use a constant that I calculate in size myself to read from the array, or take a size penalty of a few bytes in my array by padding it (my least favorite option.)

If there is something I'm misunderstanding about why Marshal wants to align the memory or anything else please feel free to enlighten me and give me suggestions as to which approach is the b est.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am sending data over a network. To send that data over a network I am packing it into a byte array.

Don't do this.

`Marshal` and `StructLayout` is intended for native interop use, not for network IO and seralization.

The correct way to serialize an object instance for IO is to write it manually, that way you get precise control over the serialized representation and can guarantee the correct format (right down the endianness of multi-byte values). Use a `BinaryWriter` (or better yet, Jon Skeet's `MiscUtil. EndianBinaryReader`: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/ ).

```
struct Foo {
    public const  Int32 Size = sizeof(Byte) + (sizeof(Single) * 3);
    public Byte   B;
    public Single F1;
    public Single F2;
    public Single F3;

    public void Serialize(EndianBinaryWriter wtr) {
        wtr.Write( Size );
        wtr.Write( B );
        wtr.Write( F1 );
        wtr.Write( F2 );
        wtr.Write( F3 );
    }

    public static Foo Deserialize(EndianBinaryReader rdr) {
        if( rdr.ReadInt32() != Size ) throw new ...
        Foo f;
        f.B  = rdr.ReadByte();
        f.F1 = rdr.ReadSingle();
        f.F2 = rdr.ReadSingle();
        f.F3 = rdr.ReadSingle();
        return f;
    }
}
```

Think of this as a kind-of `ISerializable`-lite. You would use this in a network program by having a `Stream` object that corresponds to your open network socket connection then wrapping it around the `EndianBinaryWriter|Reader` objects and doing all IO operations through those objects. As a bonus, you get disk serialization for free: just use a `FileStream` instead of a network stream.

Comment: The method you described is actually how I'm packing the data. My question was relating to more that when I pack the struct, it's 13 bytes, as I would expect, but then when I read it if I try to read it by using the size of a struct (ie Marshal.sizeOf(typeof(Type)) it returns 16 bytes because (from what I assume) the efficiency of aligning the bytes to 16 bytes. I'm simply asking if I should just read the array using the size I know of the type and change that size every time I add more data to the structure myself by updating some value.

Comment: @DYamamoto With serialization, it's best to write a header for each object that is self-describing: it should include some kind of magic string (to identify the object type), a version number, and the length of the serialized object in bytes. Then you read that back from the stream and use that as the basis for reading the object.

Comment: @DYamamoto I have amended my code with an example that checks and writes size information.